# Page Closing Event Or Preview Unloaded?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Firstly, thank you for taking the time out to read this post.

Let me get straight to my questions.

Is there any way to catch if a WPF page is closing before it is closed? i.e. some kind of PreviewClosing event? I have noticed that there is an Unloaded event, but I need something to trigger before the page is closed.

My applications has a **Window**. The main body of the **Window** contains a **Frame**, the frame is then used to navigate to a **Page**.

**WPF Window XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" />
</Grid>
```

**C# Navigates my Window Frame to a Page named SpecEditor**

```
_mainFrame.Navigate(new SpecEditor(customerDetails));
```

I need some way to trigger an event in the **SpecEditor Page** when the hosting Window is trying to close (i.e. a PreviewClosing event), so that I can perfrom various checks. Mainly to prompt the user to save any unsaved work.

Any ideas how I can get around this as the page doesn't seem to have any PreviewClosing or PreviewUnloaded events.

Thank you again for your time.

****** EDIT **************

Ok I've managed to figure out what I need.

In the main window I assign the PreviewClosing event:

```
private void RadWindow_PreviewClosed(object sender, WindowPreviewClosedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

To access the "Frame" in the main window you can use the following (note I named my frame to _mainFrame):

```
this._mainFrame.Content
```

In my case, the page which is hosted in the Frame is named "SpecEditor" which contains a docking control. So to access the content of my page I can do the following:

```
((SpecEditor)this._mainFrame.Content).radDocking
```

It casts the content of my frame (which is the page) to my custom page class (SpecEditor) which allows me to access it's content, such as my Docking control.

For good coding it is worth checking that the frame content is actually the page you're trying to cast to. You can do this like so:

```
if (this._mainFrame.Content is SpecEditor)
    {
      ((SpecEditor)this._mainFrame.Content).radDocking
      .... etc etc
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you are really using frames, this post shows an alternate approach:
https://highfieldtales.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/how-to-prevent-the-navigation-off-a-page-in-wpf/

The author uses the events for the frame's navigation facility.